# how to substract one column from different data with multiple condition

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, subset

I have two data set (data1 and Data2). I need to make new data set with the following conditions:
1. First match the date and Date from both data set (data1 and Data2), then,
2. If the Hour from data1 is smaller or equal to Hour from Data2 subtract  data1$CO2 from Data2$CO2 (data1$CO2-Data2$CO2).
Thank you in advance.

#data1
|Hour   |date   |CO2|
|:----|:----|:----|
|9  |10/1/2020  |60651|
|23 |10/1/2020  |15663|
|13 |10/1/2020  |77181|
|7  |10/1/2020  |31595|
|22 |10/1/2020  |30017|
|9  |10/1/2020  |112285|
|0  |10/1/2020  |33829|
|11 |10/1/2020  |98260|
|7  |10/1/2020  |34427|
|22 |11/1/2020  |52289|
|4  |11/1/2020  |13851|
|7  |11/1/2020  |48847|
|10 |11/1/2020  |53577|
|0  |11/1/2020  |94340|
|12 |11/1/2020  |57698|
|23 |11/1/2020  |25474|
|15 |11/1/2020  |107757|
|13 |11/1/2020  |74622|
|23 |9/1/2020   |11715|
|22 |9/2/2020   |25700|
|10 |9/3/2020   |40783|
|1  |9/4/2020   |87467|
|0  |9/5/2020   |47500|
|8  |9/6/2020   |3789|
|8  |12/1/2020  |52998|
|10 |12/1/2020  |41810|
|10 |12/1/2020  |147901|
|6  |12/1/2020  |48793|
|6  |12/1/2020  |26056|
|7  |12/1/2020  |52276|

#data2
|Date   |Hour   |CO2|
|:----|:-----|:-----|
|9/1/2020   |4  |13057|
|9/1/2020   |12 |11379|
|9/1/2020   |22 |9378|
|9/9/2020   |4  |9211|
|9/9/2020   |12 |13547|
|9/9/2020   |22 |8061|
|10/1/2020  |4  |10657|
|10/1/2020  |12 |11662|
|10/1/2020  |22 |9171|
|11/1/2020  |4  |10186|
|11/1/2020  |12 |8935|
|11/1/2020  |22 |11408|
|11/11/2020 |4  |9017|
|11/15/2020 |12 |8128|
|12/3/2020  |22 |11052|
|12/7/2020  |4  |10449|
|12/11/2020 |12 |10508|
|9/5/2020   |4  |9378|
|9/7/2020   |22 |8899|
|9/9/2020   |4  |9211|
|1/1/2021   |4  |9585|
|1/5/2021   |12 |11964|
|1/9/2021   |4  |13129|

Comment: Improve data Structure, Also Include your expected result

Comment: I have improved the data structure. Thank you for the sugessation.

Comment: You need to parse string, Also I can't provide any answer, It you don't provide your expected output.

Comment: There is many matched date, do you want to subtract  data from all of matched items OR only first matched item ?

Comment: yes, I want to subtract data from all matched times

Answer (score 1):

At First you need to parse String, And convert into Multi-Dimensional arrays.

```js
let input1 = "|9 |10/1/2020 |60651| |23 |10/1/2020 |15663| |13 |10/1/2020 |77181| |7 |10/1/2020 |31595| |22 |10/1/2020 |30017| |9 |10/1/2020 |112285| |0 |10/1/2020 |33829| |11 |10/1/2020 |98260| |7 |10/1/2020 |34427| |22 |11/1/2020 |52289| |4 |11/1/2020 |13851| |7 |11/1/2020 |48847| |10 |11/1/2020 |53577| |0 |11/1/2020 |94340| |12 |11/1/2020 |57698| |23 |11/1/2020 |25474| |15 |11/1/2020 |107757| |13 |11/1/2020 |74622| |23 |9/1/2020 |11715| |22 |9/2/2020 |25700| |10 |9/3/2020 |40783| |1 |9/4/2020 |87467| |0 |9/5/2020 |47500| |8 |9/6/2020 |3789| |8 |12/1/2020 |52998| |10 |12/1/2020 |41810| |10 |12/1/2020 |147901| |6 |12/1/2020 |48793| |6 |12/1/2020 |26056| |7 |12/1/2020 |52276|"
let input2 = "|9/1/2020 |4 |13057| |9/1/2020 |12 |11379| |9/1/2020 |22 |9378| |9/9/2020 |4 |9211| |9/9/2020 |12 |13547| |9/9/2020 |22 |8061| |10/1/2020 |4 |10657| |10/1/2020 |12 |11662| |10/1/2020 |22 |9171| |11/1/2020 |4 |10186| |11/1/2020 |12 |8935| |11/1/2020 |22 |11408| |11/11/2020 |4 |9017| |11/15/2020 |12 |8128| |12/3/2020 |22 |11052| |12/7/2020 |4 |10449| |12/11/2020 |12 |10508| |9/5/2020 |4 |9378| |9/7/2020 |22 |8899| |9/9/2020 |4 |9211| |1/1/2021 |4 |9585| |1/5/2021 |12 |11964| |1/9/2021 |4 |13129|"

function parse(string) {
    let array = string.split(/\|| /g).filter(o => o), result = [];
    while (array.length) result.push(array.splice(0, 3))
    return result;
}

let data1 = parse(input1)
let data2 = parse(input2)

console.log("data1", data1)
console.log("data2", data2)
```